# Change color of Button on click while keeping its shape

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

The code below changes the background color of the button from green to red when clicked, where the appropriate MvxColor's for bgColor are defined in my StartStopCommand. It works, but the MvxBind BackgroundColor overrides the shape of the Button.

Is there a way to keep this shape in Android and only change the color in such a way that it does not require platform specific code (as below)?

The button in Android:

```
<Button
            android:text="Start"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            local:MvxBind="Click StartStopCommand; BackgroundColor bgColor, Converter=NativeColor" />
```

where the shape xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <corners
  android:radius="10dp"
/>
  <solid
  android:color="#3497db"
/>
  <size
  android:width="270dp"
  android:height="60dp"
/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting a `Background` resource for your button, using `BackgroundColor` later will just discard everything you set there.

What you probably want is a `Selector` for your `Background` resource, which determines what is set when the `Button` is normal, focused, active and whatever other states you want to respond to. This is a very platform specific thing and you probably won't be able to reuse the behavior on other platforms.

Anyways. You could try something like this:

**shape_selected.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
  android:shape="rectangle" >
  <corners android:radius="10dp" />
  <solid android:color="#dddddd" /> <!-- use selected color here -->
  <size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

**shape_unselected.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
  android:shape="rectangle" >
  <corners android:radius="10dp" />
  <solid android:color="#3497db" />
  <size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

**button_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_unselected" />
</selector>
```

Then you would use `button_background` for your `Button`s `Background` property:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    local:MvxBind="Click StartStopCommand" />
```

Otherwise if you want to keep using your property to set the `BackgroundColor` without nuking the shape, you will need to use the `Background` property instead, have a converter which dynamically builds the shape drawable.

So in your converter you would just return a `ShapeDrawable` with your color, which you could build like this:

```
private ShapeDrawable CreateShapeDrawable(Color color)
{
    var roundRect = new RoundRectShape (new [] { 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f }, null, null);
    var shape = new ShapeDrawable (roundRect) {
        Paint = new Paint { Color = color }
    };
    return shape;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Something like this would probably work for a converter approach:

```
public class MyStateToDrawableConverter : MvxValueConverter<MvxColor, Drawable>
{
    protected override Drawable Convert(MvxColor value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return CreateShapeDrawable(value.ToNative());
    }

    private ShapeDrawable CreateShapeDrawable(Color color)
    {
        var roundRect = new RoundRectShape (new [] { 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f }, null, null);
        var shape = new ShapeDrawable (roundRect) {
            Paint = new Paint { Color = color }
        };
        return shape;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with the selector before, but it didn't work since the button only became red on pressing the button and did not stay red. I'm looking for something like a switch, i.e., it changes the button from one color to the other after pressing. Would've thought you could bind to the<solid
  android:color="#3497db"
/> somehow.. then I wouldn't have to create a platform specific converter. thx for the info ;)

Comment: You can't bind Android Resources unless it is a Layout. So the converter is probably your best bet and building or returning a Drawable for the background in there depending on the color you have for your state in your VM. So only the last part applies I guess and just chuck that into a converter.

Answer (score 1):

**button_selected**

```
<solid android:color="@color/btn_grey" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/transparant" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
```

**button_unselected**

```
<solid android:color="@color/orange_500" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/transparant" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
```

**In java file**

private Button btnMap;

btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_map);

if(bool)
{
btnMap.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selected));
}

else {
btnMap.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_unselected));